# How to trigger a workflow from another workflow using GitHub Actions?

Tags: version-control, github-actions, git-tag

I want to read version from a file and create tag as `v11.0.5.1.aws` using the workflow . Then I                                                                                                                                             want to use that tag in the docker image.
For that, I have created a branch as devops.

First created a VERSION file as

```
1.1.3 20 Apr, 2022
```

Created a workflow as release-version.yml

```
name: Release Version
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - devops
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - name: Bump version and push tag
    uses: melheffe/version_release_composer@master
    env:
      PREPEND: 'v'
      APPEND: '.aws' # must include '.' or it will append without separation
      DRAFT: 'false'
      PRERELEASE: 'true'
      TOKEN: ${{ secrets.AUTH_TOKEN }}
      TRIGGER: ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }} # can use the triggering branch or define a     fixed one like this: 'master'
      REPO_OWNER: rohit
      VERSION_FILE_NAME: 'VERSION'
```

Then created another workflow as ci.yml which will get tag from release-version workflow

```
name: CI

# Only trigger, when the build workflow succeeded
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Release Version"]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

  DeployDev:
    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    name: Deploy to Dev
    needs: [Build]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
      name: Dev

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.AUTH_TOKEN }}

      - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
        id: build-image
        #env:
        #  IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
        run: |
          # Build a docker container and push it to ECR so that it can
          # be deployed to ECS.
          echo "$GITHUB_REF_NAME"
          docker build -t ${{secrets.ECR_REPO_URI}}/${{secrets.REPO_NAME}}:$GITHUB_REF_NAME .
          docker push ${{secrets.ECR_REPO_URI}}/${{secrets.REPO_NAME}}:$GITHUB_REF_NAME
```

I'm able to trigger release version workflow after making changes on devops branch but ci workflow is not getting triggered after triggering the release-version.
Any suggestion will be helpful for me.

Comment: Do you mean that the workflow_run trigger isn't working as expected?

Comment: yes, workflow_run is not working as I was expecting it should trigger ci workflow

Comment: There doesn't seem to have any syntax problem on your workflow, so the only reason I see for the second workflow for not being triggered, is that the first one didn't completed. But that would be strange. Another option I can think of is using a `workflow_dispatch` or a `repository_dispatch` event to trigger the second workflow from the first one, sending the TAG version as input. Would that be an option? (I can share a full answer about those 2 if you wish with some references).

Comment: As GuiFalourd mentioned, I would add to the initial workflow another step "Dispatch CI".  In the "CI" workflow, I would add `workflow_dispatch`, with relevant inputs. If you intend to use Bash to dispatch the workflow, here's how I do it - https://github.com/unfor19/hero-action/blob/87eebe6c644fb03f294d70e2e76a98d757d900e3/entrypoint.sh#L117-L147

Comment: @GuiFalourd My first workflow was completed but couldn't initiated second one. You can share the full answer that would be helpful for me.

Comment: Do you want an answer with a workaround using a dispatch event?

Comment: yes @GuiFalourd

Comment: I added an answer @ROHIT BANSAL, let me know if you need more details :)

Answer (score 9):

If the `workflow_run` trigger isn't working as expected, there are two other ways to achieve what you want (triggering a workflow from another workflow, sending an input parameter from the first one to use in the second one).

- The [workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) event.
- The [repository_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) event.

The documentation is very good about how to use them, but I'll add here some references that can help as well:

- [Triggering Github Action using a POST request (Github REST API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67876177/triggering-github-action-using-a-post-request-github-rest-api/67879087#67879087)
- [How to trigger a `workflow_dispatch` from Github API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70151645/how-to-trigger-a-workflow-dispatch-from-github-api/70154713#70154713)
- [Triggering GitHub workflow using `gh` CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71972073/253468)

As you can see, you can trigger those events using directly the Github API in a step (with a CURL request) or using some actions from the Github Marketplace that perform the same operation.

The answer below also explains the difference between both events (as they are similar, and CURL payload differences may be confusing)

- [Correct request with client-payload to run workflow_dispatch in github action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69925264/correct-request-with-client-payload-to-run-workflow-dispatch-in-github-action/69930019#69930019)

I'll also add here an example that can be useful to understand how to use the `repository_dispatch` event to receive a `callback` from the other workflow to the first one:

- [workflow A](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/04-dispatch-event-workflow.yml)
- [workflow B](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/ritchie-formulas-scheduler-demo/blob/main/.github/workflows/6-formulas-scheduler-remote-dispatch.yml)

Note that you will also need to use a [PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) to trigger a workflow using a dispatch event.

Answer (score 0):

There is an important **Note** in [GitHub's documentation on `workflow_run`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_run):

> You can't use workflow_run to chain together more than three levels of workflows. For example, if you attempt to trigger five workflows (named `B` to `F`) to run sequentially after an initial workflow `A` has run (that is: `A` → `B` → `C` → `D` → `E` → `F`), workflows `E` and `F` will not be run.

Perhaps you have a chain with more than three levels of workflows?