# How to communicate [request for action and wait for its status] between two different repositories in Github Actions?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, github-actions

I have a backend running in rails and frontend in react, I want to trigger deployment from GA of backend repo (achieved via hitting github api) and trying to wait for the deployment status in that aciton.

After deployment I want to ship the full stack application, run the initial testing a whole lot of possible automated stuff

Comment: How do you check the back-end deployment status today? Would it be possible to do it through command line (through a loop for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer for the actual question -
[url-health-check-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/url-health-check) from the marketplace:

```
jobs:
  deployment: 
    ...
    ...
  
  wait:
    needs: deployment
    steps:
    - name: Check the deployed service URL
      uses: jtalk/url-health-check-action@v3
      with:
        url: https://example.com|http://example.com
        max-attempts: 3 
        retry-delay: 5s
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71955944/1432893) answer covers really well all the different approaches to how trigger another workflow so I wont go in detail into that.

My two cents:

I wanted to question the idea of tying together a succesful deployment of component A with testing of component B.

If the the source code of the backend and front is separated into two repositories, I assume their development lifecycle is as well independent of one another. Calling the testing phase of the frontend only AFTER successful deployment of the backend means you'll be exposing yourself to:

- failed backend not triggering potentially successful frontend
- running backend while frontend is failing and waiting till fix.

I would try to separate the responsibilities of workflows to - testing and building per repo, and add another orchestrating workflow for the deployment of the artifacts.

Comment: I am expecting a way, maybe it is not there or I might be connecting dots differently!
and I am exposing myself to these failure possibilites that frontend build not succeeded beause after hitting login or root url would give me a automated report [or a simple flag boolean] which could add the comment, something went wrong.
If deployment of both goes well the test coverage for integrated frontend and backend would give me end to end funtionality overview

You are right, testing both component individually should get us to conclusion that every thing is right to the expectation,
Thanks